# Comparing Multiple Cells and Returning Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
  A     B          C   D
1 Bob   10/02/2013 10

2 Bob   10/02/2013 2

3 Bob   10/02/2013 8

4 Steve 10/01/2013 6

5 Steve 10/01/2013 6

6 Sally 10/01/2013 6
```

The requirement is that if A1 matches anything else in column A (A1,A2, and A3) AND B1 matches anything in column B (B1,B2,B3) Then add up the values C, divide by 4 and put that in D.

I want to do this for the whole sheet (500ish rows).

Comment: Im not sure if I understand completely, do you want to sum values in C only if there is another match?
Can you tell us what you would expect to be in column D in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `SUMIFS` function. Below is sample.

Formula `=SUMIFS(C1:C5,A1:A5,A1,B1:B5,B1)`

[image]
OR

[image]

Or can use `SUMPRODUCT` function .

`=SUMPRODUCT($C$1:$C$5,--($A$1:$A$5=$A1)*--($B$1:$B$5=B1))/4`

[image]

Comment: Hi Santosh! This is nearly perfect, thank you so much for your help.